# Cannot create a conditional publication based on a user-defined type on PostgreSQL 15

Tags: postgresql, logical-replication, postgresql-15

I am trying to publicate the `cnt_title` table using PostgreSQL Logical Replication. Note that I only want to share the product titles.

```sql
create publication cnt_publication_for_stk for table 
cnt_title where (doc_type = 'PRODUCT');
```

What I have found is a syntax error saying `User-defined types are not allowed.` This is consistent with the idea of `docs_type` being a column of custom type `tdoc`, defined as

```sql
create type tdoc as enum (
  'ARTICLE', 
  'PRODUCT', 
  'VOUCHER' 
);
```

**Is there any work around for this expression?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a lookup table instead of an enum type. That is, use a table:

```
CREATE TABLE doctype (
   id smallint PRIMARY KEY,
   name text UNIQUE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO doctype VALUES
   (1, 'ARTICLE'),
   (2, 'PRODUCT'),
   (3, 'VOUCHER');
```

and use the primary key instead of the enum value.

Comment: This is basically what a enum type is behind the scenes, so I imagine this limitation will disappear in future versions

Comment: Waiting for this feature for son long and finally does now work with enums! :-)

Comment: This limitation may never be lifted. How can you guarantee that user-defined types are the same on both sides? On the other hand, postgres_fdw allows you to define what you want to push down...

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/logical-replication-row-filter.html), row filter expressions cannot contain user-defined functions, operators, **types**, and collations, system column references or non-immutable built-in functions.

In addition, if a publication publishes `UPDATE` or `DELETE` operations, the row filter `WHERE` clause must contain only columns that are covered by the replica identity

Comment: Yes, as I said in the OP, I'm aware of this. That is why I asked for a work around